# Как добавить текстовую информацию в контрол DataGridTextColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentItems}"
          LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow"
          RowHeaderWidth="50" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFB0B0B0" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFB0B0B0" Sorting="DataGrid_Sorting">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Prop1}" Header="Заголовок0" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Prop2}" Header="Заголовок1" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Prop3}" Header="Заголовок2" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Prop4}" Header="Заголовок3" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Prop5}" Header="Зфголовок4" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Я хочу обработать событие `Sorting` у `DataGrid`

В этом случае к базе должен отправиться новый запрос с указанием столбца. Получить столбец в базе я могу через биндинг столбца на форме. То есть из Prop1 я могу получить Field1, но как мне это получить? В обработчике события у меня есть `E.Column` типа `DataGridColumn`

Тэга у столбца нет. К свойству Binding я почему то обратиться из кода не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение

```
var colBind = ((e.Column as DataGridTextColumn)?.Binding as Binding)?.Path?.Path;
```